# Path From and To Same Node in tikz Flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, nodes, node-connections

I'm working on creating flowcharts directly inside LaTeX documents using tikz. I am admittedly an extreme novice with tikz, although I have quite a bit of experience using LaTeX.

My problem is when trying to show an endless loop with the flowchart, i.e., an edge or path that starts and ends at the same node.

For example,

[image: this image]

is an example of what I want (right) and what I'm getting (left) using the following LaTeX code:

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}

\tikzstyle{decision} = [ diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep-0pt]  
\tikzstyle{block} = [ rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, text badly centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]  
\tikzstyle{line} = [ draw, -latex']  
\tikzstyle{terminator} = [ draw, ellipse, fill=red!20, node distance=3cm, minimum height=2em]  

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, auto]  
  \node [terminator]           (puc)  {Power-Up Reset};  
  \node [block, below of=puc]  (wdt)  {Stop Watchdog};  
  \node [block, below of=wdt]  (port) {Setup Port Pins};  
  \node [block, below of=port] (loop) {Loop Forever};  
  \path [line] (puc)  -- (wdt);  
  \path [line] (wdt)  -- (port);  
  \path [line] (port) -- (loop);  
  \path [line] (loop) -- (loop);  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I assume I'm going to need something a bit more complex.

Comment: @Thorsten: My editing interfered with your editing.

Comment: @Zanfar: I put the image into the post for ya'. Feel free to rollback if you don't like it.

Comment: @Yossi: you should be aware that doing that isn't _always_ helpful.  If the questioner doesn't have enough rep to do that themselves, then putting it in means that if they edit the question, they have to remove the image.

Comment: hmmm. I did realize that. @Zanfar: if you want to edit your question, let me know and I'll re-add the image after your edits, if you want.

Comment: @Andrew, @Yossi: the “remove new user restrictions” is (currently) at 10 rep, so after a question is upvoted two times, there is no problem with adding a picture.

Comment: @Caramdir: you're right, it is currently low.  But I got caught by it once before, and I think that when we leave beta the limit will go up so it's a good habit to get in to now.

Comment: @Andrew: it is also 10 rep on stack overflow, so i do not think it will get higher (it is just an anti-spam measure).

Comment: @Caramdir: I stand (sit/type/whatever) corrected.  I'll go back in my shell now (which is, naturally, drawn in TikZ).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Simply change `\path [line] (loop) -- (loop);` to `\path [line] (loop) edge[loop right] ();` (or `loop below` or `loop left`).

[image: example 1]

Alternatively, change it to `\path [line] (loop) |- ($(loop.south east) + (0.5,-0.5)$) |- (loop);` (with `\usetikzlibrary{calc}`) for

[image: example 2]

Further, adding `rounded corners` (e.g. `\path [line,rounded corners] (loop) |- ($(loop.south east) + (0.5,-0.5)$) |- (loop);`) gives

[image: example 3]

Comment: What happens if you do `(loop.south) to[out=-90,in=0] (loop.east)`?  (Nice answer, btw)

Comment: Thanks, all those options work perfectly.
Andrew: <code>(loop.south) to[out=-90,in=0] (loop.east)</code> cuts across the lower-right corner of the box.

Comment: [This happens](http://caramdir.at/uploads/tex.SE/5114-wrong-path.png). (@Zanfar: use backticks ` for code in comments)

Comment: I tried adding `looseness=3` which means that it doesn't cut across the box, but it still looks pretty ugly.  I was trying to avoid having to specify a third coordinate.

Answer (score 2):

A few more details in for of a minimal example could have been very helpful because there are some tikZ libraries necessary to compile your example.

You can get the desired loop can by adding a coordinate to the last path that forces the path to be drawn through this point.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\tikzstyle{decision}=[diamond,draw,fill=blue!20,text width=4.5em,text badly centered,node distance=3cm,inner sep=0pt]  
\tikzstyle{block}=[rectangle,draw,fill=blue!20,text width=5em,text badly centered,rounded corners,minimum height=4em]  
\tikzstyle{line}=[draw,-latex']  
\tikzstyle{terminator}=[draw,ellipse,fill=red!20,node distance=3cm,minimum height=2em]  

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,auto]  
    \node[terminator]           (puc)  {Power-Up Reset};  
    \node[block, below of=puc]  (wdt)  {Stop Watchdog};  
    \node[block, below of=wdt]  (port) {Setup Port Pins};  
    \node[block, below of=port] (loop) {Loop Forever};  
    \path[line] (puc)  -- (wdt);  
    \path[line] (wdt)  -- (port);  
    \path[line] (port) -- (loop);  
    \path[line] (loop) |- +(2,-1) |- (loop.east);  
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```