# Arrow from node back to itself

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, arrows

I've tried to follow [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354199/how-to-make-an-arrow-from-a-node-to-itself-have-a-nice-arc) in search for how to draw an Arrow in a nice loop from one node back to itself, but I can't figure out why my code doesn't provide me a loop. In the code below, I want the node with label A to have a loop back to itself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,decorations,automata,backgrounds,petri}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
    \node (A) at (0,3) {A};
    \node (B) at (3,3) {B};
    \node (C) at (6,3) {C};
    \node (D) at (6,0) {D};
    \node (E) at (6,-3) {E};
    \node (F) at (3,-3) {F};
    \node (G) at (0,-3) {G};
    \node (H) at (0,0) {H};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[>={Stealth[black]},
              every node/.style={fill=white,circle},
              every edge/.style={draw=black}]

    \path [red,->] (A.90) arc (0:264:4mm) node {$xx$} (A);
    \path [->] (A) edge node {$xx$} (B);
    \path [->] (A) edge[bend left=60] node {$xx$} (C);
    \path [->] (A) edge node {$xx$} (D);
    \path [->] (A) edge node {$xx$} (E);
    \path [->] (A) edge node {$xx$} (F);
    \path [->] (A) edge[bend right=60] node {$xx$} (G);
    \path [->] (A) edge node {$xx$} (H);

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the arrow doesn't "bend out" of the node..

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\path` doesn't draw any lines unless you add `draw` in the options, so you need `\path [draw,..`, or just `\draw` instead of `\path`.

You probably also want to move the node with `pos`, so have something like

```
\draw [red,->] (A.90) arc (0:264:4mm) node[pos=0.5,above left] {$xx$} (A);
```

[image]

Comment: Torbjorn, you're always answering my questions. Are you the king of Latex? :) Thank you a lot, it worked like a charm.